# Segmentation fault after invoking free() method but only with certain values

Tags: parameters, malloc, free, behavior

I've got this little simple program in C, I post its code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char *char_ptr;
int *int_ptr;
int mem_size;

if (argc<2) {
mem_size = 50;
}
else
{
mem_size = atoi(argv[1]);
}

printf("\t[+] allocating %d bytes of memory on the heap for char_ptr\n", mem_size);
char_ptr = (char *) malloc(mem_size);
if(char_ptr == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memory.\n");
exit(-1);
}
strcpy(char_ptr, "This memory is in the heap segment");
printf("char_ptr (%p) -> '%s'\n", char_ptr, char_ptr);

printf("\t[+] allocating 12 bytes of memory on the heap for int_ptr\n");
int_ptr = (int *)malloc(12);

if(int_ptr == NULL){
fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memory.\n");
exit(-1);
}

*int_ptr = 31337;

printf("int_ptr (%p) --> %d\n", int_ptr, *int_ptr);
printf("\t[-] freeing char_ptr's heap memory...\n");
free(char_ptr);

printf("\t[+] allocating another 17 bytes for char_ptr\n");
char_ptr = (char *) malloc(17);

if(char_ptr == NULL){
fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memory.\n");
exit(-1);
}

strcpy(char_ptr, "New Memory");
printf("char_ptr (%p) --> '%s'\n", char_ptr, char_ptr);
printf("\t[-] freeing int_ptr's heap memory.\n");
free(int_ptr);
printf("\t[-] freeing char_ptr's memory\n");
free(char_ptr);
printf("Program exiting\n");
return 0;
}
```

When i run it with parameter greater or equal to 29, it's all ok..but if I place 28 or less, it goes to segmentation fault...
I was thinking about an address issue between heap and stack, the problem occurs at the free() int_ptr call.
Can anyone help me? I can't get this make any sense...

Thanks a lot everyone
Have a nice day

Comment: Please format your code a bit more with proper indenting to make it easy to read. Also please add the stack trace, that helps finding the place where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The first string you copy into the char_ptr memory (`"This memory is in the heap segment"`) is 35 bytes long including the terminating NUL byte. This will corrupt your heap for all parameters of less than 35.

Just by chance it works for you down to 29 since free probably does not rely on the data overwritten.

Comment: Hi Johannes

First of all, thank you for your response! I have actually some doubts. The problem occurrs when I allocate a mem_size lesser than 35 bytes as it tries to fit 35 bytes-long string in a shorter range of memory...this is a bug i did not notice. But i don't get why the error occurs at the end of the program. I mean, the code does some malloc-free stuff BEFORE the last free() which causes the error. I cannot get why there..and how it can run with values smaller than 35 but greater than 28. I'll try to figure it out, you gave me an important suggestion Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is because `free()` does not inspect all of the internal data of the heap, but just swivels around the pointers it needs to. It is typical for some completely unrelated `free()` to crash. 
In your case you are overwriting the metadata of the memory block which follows the `char_ptr` block. It is impossible to deterministically tell what this would be. `malloc()` and `free()` use several different memory pools internally for speed which makes them hard to predict.

In your case I assume you are simply overwriting the metadata of the `int_ptr` block so you get a crash when you free that.